# Should I use printf("\n") or putchar('\n') to print a newline in C?

Tags: c

When I'm writing a program in C, I often have to print a newline by itself. I know you can do this in at least two ways: `printf("\n")` and `putchar('\n')`, but I'm not sure which way is the best choice in terms of style and possibly efficiency. Are there any best practices for using one over the other? Does it really matter?

Comment: This kind of optimization is almost never worth worrying about. :)

Comment: beware premature optimization

Comment: What about `puts("");`?

Comment: [6.001 vs half a dozen of the other](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other)

Comment: A third option is `fprintf(stdout, "\n");`

Comment: I don't think the OP's question is which one is better optimized...but which one is more idiomatic. I am guessing `printf("\n");` because it's explicit about it's intentions and is known to newcomers without a second glance.

Comment: As this construct is used megazillion times, it is certainly worth thinking of it once for all (even if the answer could be "it makes no difference" or "it depends").

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It will make no difference which one you chose if you're using a modern compiler<sup>[1]</sup>. Take for example the following C code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    putchar('\n');
}

void bar(void) {
    printf("\n");
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -O1` (optimizations enabled), we get the following (identical) machine code in both `foo` and `bar`:

```
movl    $10, %edi
popq    %rbp
jmp _putchar                ## TAILCALL
```

Both `foo` and `bar` end up calling `putchar('\n')`. In other words, modern C compilers are smart enough to optimize `printf` calls very efficiently. Just use whichever one you think is more clear and readable.

---

1. I do not consider MS's `cl` to be a modern compiler.

Comment: @ikegami - I tried clang too. I could try `icc` as well—but I'd be *very* surprised if a commercial compiler optimized more poorly than gcc. On a related note, I've also observed that gcc will change a `printf` with only one argument (just a format string with no format specifiers) into a call to `puts` instead (assuming it ends with a newline).

Comment: @DaoWen: "I'd be very surprised if a commercial compiler optimized more poorly than gcc" ... Do you know compiler for embedded systems? You'd be surprised. And in general, I'd not imply gcc optimises worse than any other compiler - commercial or not.

Comment: @Olaf - I'd say embedded systems programming is one of the few places where you can get stuck with a really sub-par compiler today. The standard library support is usually lacking too. The last embedded system I programmed for had neither `printf` nor `malloc`—so in that case, I guess I'd have to go with `putchar('\n')`. ;)

Comment: My  embedded compiler (CCS) made such optimizations.  Same 4 instructions either way.  2 to wait for port to clear, 1 to load `'\n'` and one to write.

Comment: @DaoWen: Well, embedded has change much with ARMv7M.

Comment: @ikegami: Microsoft's `cl` is not a "modern compiler". Its design is stuck in the 80s, and so is its support for the C language.

Comment: @R., The age of its design is irrelevant. It's the compiler used to compile programs in modern times on Windows. There's nothing newer. If you have a Windows program, it's compiled by it, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @ikegami: there are alternatives in Windows to compile C programs, even those who call the Windows API.  `gcc` has been ported for that. `cl` lacks C99 support and the Microsoft C runtime library as well. I the OP cares about the C language, he probably should switch to a more modern platform altogether.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree, _she_ should.

Comment: @ikegami: "Modern compilers" means something very different from "compilers used in present day". I would include characteristics like supporting the present version of the language, using reasonable intermediate representations to apply transformations/optimizations rather than a "high level assembler" model, normalization of equivalent constructs, support for important classes of optimizations, etc. when judging whether a compiler is "modern".

Comment: @ikegami: I would read "if you're using a modern compiler" as a qualification that "it should make no difference" only applies if you're actually using a modern compiler, i.e. not vendor-supplied embedded/game-console junk or msvc or similar.

Comment: *"Modern: characterized by or using the most up-to-date techniques, ideas, or equipment."* So yes, when I say "modern compiler" I mean a compiler that strives to support a relatively-current version of the C standard, and applies relatively-current optimization techniques. A compiler that was written 20 years ago and hasn't undergone any major changes wouldn't qualify as "modern" by my standard.

Comment: @ikegami - Please don't edit my answer to reflect your personal opinions.

Comment: I had adjusted it to reflect your opinion. "*A compiler that was written 20 years ago and hasn't undergone any major changes wouldn't qualify as "modern" by my standard.*"  Maybe this wording is better?

Comment: @ikegami - Did you check the behavior of cl with regard to this optimization? Your "clarification" seems kind of pointless unless cl in fact does not do this optimization.

Answer (score 11):

> Are there any best practices for using one over the other?

Let style drives the decision.

Since efficiency of execution is the same or nearly identical, use the style that best conveys the larger code's function.

If the function had lots of `printf()`, stay with `printf("\n")`.

Likewise for `putchar('\n')` and `puts("")`

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter. I never encountered a case were printing to the console ever matter to someone in terms functions choice or effiency.

Comment: Printing to the console dramatically slows down an executing program relative to not printing. The difference is huge. Try a simple test: wite a for loop that counts to a million and does nothing else, then add a print statement inside the loop body.

Comment: of course it slows down. the point is that the difference between pritnf and putchar are not even worth troubling with. if printing to the console is your bottleneck you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If printing to the console is the purpose of the program, you're not doing something wrong.

Comment: if printing to the console is the purpose - you're probably doing something not worth optimizing.

Comment: These functions do not necessarily *print* to the console.  Output may be redirected to a file and efficiency may be a concern if large amounts of output are produced.  In this case, `putchar_unlocked('\n');` would be more efficient but hardly a better choice.

Answer (score 5):

`printf` and `putchar` are both stdio functions, so they both write to the same `FILE` handle (rather than directly to the file descriptor).

However, `printf` is far heavier since the first argument is a format string that needs to be scanned for replacement expressions and escapes.

So, both `printf("\n")` and `putchar('\n')` will do the same thing, but the latter will be faster.

Answer (score 3):

printf is much slower because the format string is parsed at runtime. Of course, the average homework program or simple Project Euler solution is so small that wasting a few CPU cycles doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Many C compilers parse a constant format string at _compile_ time and create optimized code.

Comment: True, yet If the compiler does not optimize this trivial code, then OP's optimization effort is better spent looking for a better compiler rather than `printf("\n")` vs. `putchar('\n')`.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with `putchar` as the string in `printf` needs to be parsed. Should be slightly quicker - but probably not a lot in it.